# system.invalidoperationexception

Tags: c#, transactions, invalidoperationexception, sqlcedatareader

I am trying to run this code

```
public Exception SetData(string Data , long NoOfColumnsAllowed)
    {
        try
        {
            con = new SqlCeConnection(conectionstring);
            con.Open();
            transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
            com = new SqlCeCommand();
            com.Transaction = transaction;
            com.CommandText = "Select  count(*) from [Copy]";
            com.Connection = con;
            sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                noOfColumns = sdr.GetInt32(0);
            }


            if (noOfColumns > NoOfColumnsAllowed)
            {
                long NoOfColumsToBeDeleted = noOfColumns - NoOfColumnsAllowed;
                com.CommandText = "delete from [Copy] where Sno<=@sno";
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sno", NoOfColumsToBeDeleted);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            com.CommandText = "Insert into [Copy] (Data) values (@data)";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", Data);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
            con.Close();

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            con.Close();
            return ex;
        }


    }
```

Exception Occur -

> *system.invalidoperationexception : The transaction can not be
>   committed if there is any opened cursor in the scope of this
>   transaction . Make sure all the data readers/ result sets are
>   explicitly closed before committing the change .*

I am new with transaction and not able to find any valuable solution about opened cursor. Is there something wrong with code or i have to explicitly close the data reader if yes please tell me how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call sdr.Close(); right after the while loop since that's what error is complaining about.